# Translate "How do I ask my girlfriend how cook pasta?"

Tags: grammar, translation

I want to translate in korean the question:

> How do I ask my girlfriend how to cook pasta?

I made an attempt:

> 제 여자친구한테 어떻게 파스타를 요리하다고 어떻게 칠문해요?

The rationale behind it is

> 1. How do I ask? -> 어떻게 칠문해요?
> 2. To my girfriend -> 제여자친구한테
> 3. How to cook pasta -> 파스타 어떻게 요리해요

But 3. Is the quoted question so I put the quotation 다고

Is it correct and natural to say?

Comment: -다고 is for a quoted statement, not a question. You use -냐고 for a quoted question. So correcting your translation:
제 여자친구에게 어떻게 파스타를 요리하냐고 어떻게 질문해요?

Comment: But apart from this. Seems correct?

Answer (score 0):

@MujjinGun's comment ("제 여자친구에게 어떻게 파스타를 요리하냐고 어떻게 질문해요?") is a good literal translation, but let me suggest an alternative.

Frequently, English phrase "how to ..." is better translated to "...하는 법" or "...하는 방법" (literally, "the method to do ...").  So, we can say:

> (제) 여자친구에게 파스타 요리하는 법을 어떻게 물어봐요?

In this particular case, you can even shorten "요리하는 법" into one word:

> (제) 여자친구에게 파스타 요리법을 어떻게 물어봐요?

("물어보다" and "질문하다" roughly mean the same, but I think "물어보다" is a bit more conversational.)